# How can I see the history log of system updates?

Tags: updates, rom, ota-update, system, logging

I need to know the history log of system updates (ROM / OTA updates). Is there any file on the device that contains this information?

Comment: My Sony phone has a "update history" which lists every installed OTA update version number + date, but this seems to be a modification by Sony. My Lenovo tablet has no such update history. Hence it depends on your phone. You should edit your question and add details about your phone like manufacturer and model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most OEM doesn't keep a log of that on your device, but the recovery (a place for installing OTA updates) does keep a log of what you installed, when you wiped data, etc. That log should be in `/cache/recovery/last_log`